# How to reduce the gap between the name/program and the line beneath

Tags: header-footer

This is the code

```
% Source: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5374/23931
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.3mm}}

\makeatletter% since there's an at-sign (@) in the command name
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
  \parindent=0pt% don't indent paragraphs in the title block
  % \centering
  % {\Large \bfseries\textsc{\@title}}
  {\@author \hfill \@date }
  \HRule\par
    \centering
  \vspace*{10pt}{\underline{\Large \bfseries\textsc{\@title}}}\vspace*{10pt}
  
}
\makeatother% resets the meaning of the at-sign (@)

\title{Statement of Purpose}
\author{Name}
\date{Program}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle% prints the title block

\parindent=0pt
\input{SOP}
  
\end{document}
```

and this is the result

[image]

I want to reduce the gap between name/program and the line beneath and make it like a header in word file.

Comment: `\par\vspace{-5pt}\HRule\par`  or whatever value you like

Comment: The source for `\maketitle` can be found in `article.cls` (if you want a complete replacement).

Comment: Or use `titling`.