# How to bring left right text to the above line?

Tags: tables, header-footer, format

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
% Source: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5374/23931
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor} % Add the xcolor package
\usepackage{biblatex} %Imports biblatex package
\addbibresource{papers.bib} %Import the bibliography file
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=green,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcommand{\Hrule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.3mm}}

\makeatletter% since there's an at-sign (@) in the command name
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
  \parindent=0pt% don't indent paragraphs in the title block
  \centering
  {\Large \bfseries\textsc{\@title}}
  \HRule\par%
  \textit{\@author \hfill \@date}
  \par
}
\makeatother% resets the meaning of the at-sign (@)

\title{Statement of Purpose}
\author{\textcolor{blue}{ \textbf{Tim hammerberg}}}
\date{\textcolor{blue}{ \textbf{hammerberg.github.io}}}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle% prints the title block
  \vspace{0.4em}
Recent breakthroughs in natural language processing (NLP) have unlocked remarkable capabilities. However, there are still core limitations concerning efficiency.
\end{document}
```

I want Tim hammerberg and hammerberg.github.io just above line, how to do it?

Comment: You can either rewrite `\maketitle` or just not use it.  The work required is about the same either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor} % Add the xcolor package
\usepackage{biblatex} %Imports biblatex package
\addbibresource{papers.bib} %Import the bibliography file
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=green,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcommand{\Hrule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.3mm}}

\makeatletter% since there's an at-sign (@) in the command name
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
    \parindent=0pt% don't indent paragraphs in the title block
    \centering
    {\Large \bfseries\textsc{\@title}}\par%
    \textit{\@author \hfill \@date}\par%
    \HRule%
%   \par
}
\makeatother% resets the meaning of the at-sign (@)

\title{Statement of Purpose}
\author{\textcolor{blue}{ \textbf{Tim hammerberg \vspace{-2ex}}}}
\date{\textcolor{blue}{ \textbf{hammerberg.github.io}}}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle% prints the title block
    \vspace{0.8em}
    Recent breakthroughs in natural language processing (NLP) have unlocked remarkable capabilities. However, there are still core limitations concerning efficiency.
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT To remove spacing before title change geometry to

```
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor} % Add the xcolor package
\usepackage{biblatex} %Imports biblatex package
\addbibresource{papers.bib} %Import the bibliography file
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titling}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=green,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
}



\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcommand{\Hrule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.3mm}}

\makeatletter% since there's an at-sign (@) in the command name
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
    \parindent=0pt% don't indent paragraphs in the title block
    \centering
    \setlength{\droptitle}{-3cm}
    {\Large \bfseries\textsc{\@title}}\par%
    \textit{\@author \hfill \@date}\par%
    \HRule%
%   \par
}
\makeatother% resets the meaning of the at-sign (@)

\title{Statement of Purpose }
\author{\textcolor{blue}{ \textbf{Tim hammerberg \vspace{-2ex}}}}
\date{\textcolor{blue}{ \textbf{hammerberg.github.io}}}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle% prints the title block
    \vspace{0.8em}
    Recent breakthroughs in natural language processing (NLP) have unlocked remarkable capabilities. However, there are still core limitations concerning efficiency.
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you, can we reduce the top gap, it's taking too much space? the space above statement of purpose.

Comment: have a look at the edit -- also suggest to accept the answer with a green check mark if it meets your requirement -- new requirements should be presesnted as a separate new question to attract a wider audience